# Multi user login issue when I press the login button In PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$username="";
$password="";
if(isset($_POST['lusernamet']) && isset($_POST['lpasswordt'])){
    $username=$_POST['lusernamet'];
    $password=$_POST['lpasswordt'];
    if(checkAgentLogin($username, $password)){
        if($username=="$username" && $password=="$password"){
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;
            $_SESSION['agentusername']=$username;
            header("Location: agentHome.php");
         }
    }
    else if (adminLoginCheck($username, $password)){
        if($username=="$username" && $password=="$password"){
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;
            $_SESSION['admin']=$username;
            header("Location: home.php");
            }
    }
    else if (campaignAdminLoginCheck($username, $password)){
        if($username=="$username" && $password=="$password"){
                $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;
                $_SESSION['camAdminUsername']=$username;
                header("Location: campAdminHome.php");
            }
    }else{
            echo"Username/Password is Invalid";
        }   
 }
?>
```

When I used this code login check correct first one and second one but third one header redirect page is work when I input blank field and press login button. Someone help me?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's wrong when you don't include the `checkAgentLogin()`, `adminLoginCheck()` and `campaignAdminLoginCheck()` functions.

Comment: yes that is true. Thanks for you Feedback. I already solved the issue.